# Shop for new ipad apps from web?

Tags: ios-appstore

I've ordered a new ipad pro; yay!  It has yet to arrive.  In my anticipation; I'd like to browse the app store and make a list of apps to investigate.  How do I do this?

While I've owned some iphones in the past, I currently only have a mac.  The Music app, only browses the music store.  The Mac App store appears to only offer mac apps (I tried searching for Procreate and nothing shows).  If I try the web at https://www.apple.com/ios/app-store/, it only directs me to the app.  Searching generically for an app (e.g. procreate), I find https://apps.apple.com/us/app/procreate/id425073498, but url manipulation doesn't avail; I find no generic search box or navigation page.

Have I missed anything obvious?  Is there no way to see the ipad/iphone app catalog outside of one of those devices?

Comment: Apple unfortunately removed that option some time ago, same time as app management was removed from iTunes. I can't post this as an answer, because the swearing police would be sent to get me within the first paragraph ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Just post the first sentence as written :-)

Comment: @nohillside - done… though I blamed you ;-)))

Answer (score 1):

Apple unfortunately removed that option some time ago, same time as app management was removed from iTunes.

[Kept brief under advisement from a mod ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can search the internet for things like "Best Editing Apps ios" or "Top games ios" and other gazillion terms. And you should get plenty of hits. I'd take the most recent return and look at that. You'll find many dated 2020. And most matches will have things like top ten or top 20 so they'll be plenty of apps to make note off.  This will find App Store apps as well as other apps and in most cases tell you which one it is and the price.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an overview of the most popular apps here : https://apps.apple.com/us/genre/ios/id36 and sometimes the 'Open in iTunes' button will appear in the upper right corner of the screen.

Besides that, as @Tetsujin said Apple no longer allows searching from iTunes/internet.